# Error "cannot resolve type entity engcc2.matdialogmodule" while migrating to angular material 10

Tags: angular-material, angular10

Recently i have migrated Angular 8 application to angular 10 but when i updated angular material version to 10 it start giving me below error :

**cannot resolve type entity engcc2.matdialogmodule**

It is not showing any specific file. I tried google for it but din't get help which can resolve.

Below is my package.json

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ7Ek.png)

Comment: Have you replaced your `@angular/material` imports? Should now be using something like `import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';`